# How do I use "ros init" properly?

Tags: amazon-ec2, realm, realm-object-server

I have an app that works fine with Realm currently; I've got the ROS 2.0.18 running on an AWS EC2 instance, which started with a "blank" Ubuntu AMI onto which I installed/started ROS using, I believe, `curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/realm/realm-object-server/master/install.sh | bash`. It's possible I started it with `npm install -g realm-object-server`; however I'm pretty positive I've never typed `ros init`, or any versions of `ros init my-app`, at any point in any process.

I'm preparing to integrate Google Authentication, and the ROS documentation says "To include the Google provider, create a Realm Object Server project via `ros init`" and then has some code.

I imagine this means I need to SSH into my server (which is already up and running for ROS) and enter `ros init`. And then put the code from the documentation in the window that I imagine will pop up.

But I don't really know anything about `ros init` or what an ros project actually is (or node or anything like that for that matter), so I'm a little trepidatious, and these questions come up:

1. Will `ros init` mess anything up that's currently on my server? Does it "initialize" or reset anything?
2. Assuming the answer to #1 is "no", what do I do once I've pasted the code into this file (assuming I'm correct about what to do wit the code)? Do I need to make my app or my ROS instance aware of it somehow?
3. Anything else I'm missing?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of ROS is your application using right now?

Comment: I'm having trouble SSHing in to check exactly, but it's definitely v2.x

Comment: Update: I'm running 2.0.18